# .NET C++ Regex::Matches()->Count returns wrong number

Tags: .net, regex, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

I'm trying to count the number of "^" (hat symbols) inside a string, but the following code returns the wrong number.

```
Int32 lNumber = 0;
String* lString = S"abc^def^ghi^jkl";
lNumber = Regex::Matches(lString, S"\^")->Count + 1;
Console::WriteLine(lNumber);

//output:
// 2
```

However, the output should be 4. Why do I get 2 instead?

Comment: What version c++ ? Is it posix regex ? dot-net in c++ ?!?

Comment: If this is C++/CLI, then `System::String*` should be illegal (would need `String^` (Note: `c++-cli` is the correct tag, not `c++`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I changed the tag. This is a really old project I'm working on that has both managed and native C++. To be honest, I'm not sure why String* works in this particular project. Other projects in this solution do require String^ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"\\^"` and not `"\^"`. `"\^"` is the same as `"^"`, which as a regex means just "start of a line".